# generating struts2 taglib using Java6 Annotation Processor with ant

Tags: ant, struts2, taglib, apt

I have written some Struts2 taglib and want to package them into a jar.
I am not using maven so I used to use Ant with apt tag with struts-annotations-1.0.5.jar.
And my task looks like the following

```
<target name="generate-taglib" >
<apt classpathref="tags.classpath" factorypathref="tags.classpath"
            srcdir="StrutsTags" compile="false" destdir="dist/apt" fork="true"
            preprocessdir="bin" verbose="false" source="1.5" encoding="utf-8"

            factory="org.apache.struts.annotations.taglib.apt.TLDAnnotationProcessorFactory" includeantruntime="false">

            <compilerarg value="-AtlibVersion=1.0" />
            <compilerarg value="-AjspVersion=2.0" />
            <compilerarg value="-AshortName=mb" />
            <compilerarg value="-Auri=/struts-my-tags" />
            <compilerarg value="-Adescription='My Struts Tags'" />
            <compilerarg value="-AdisplayName='My Struts Tags'" />
            <compilerarg value="-AoutTemplatesDir=${basedir}/dist/taglib-doc" />
            <compilerarg value="-AoutFile=${basedir}/bin/META-INF/struts-my-tags.tld" />
        </apt>
</target>
```

However since java 6 apt has been removed or not supported I want to use the Annotation Processor in the Java Compiler. But I couldnt find any direct example and I came up with the following

```
<target name="generate-taglib" depends="compile">
       <javac destdir="bin"
          debug="true"
          failonerror="true"
          compiler="javac1.6"
          srcdir="StrutsTags" includeantruntime="false" encoding="utf-8" verbose="true">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <classpath refid="tags.classpath"/>
            <compilerarg line="-proc:only"/>
            <compilerarg line="-processor org.apache.struts.annotations.taglib.apt.TagAnnotationProcessor" />
            <compilerarg line="-s dist/apt" />
            <compilerarg line="-source 6"/>
            <compilerarg value="-AtlibVersion=1.0.1" />
            <compilerarg value="-AjspVersion=2.0" />
            <compilerarg value="-AshortName=mb" />
            <compilerarg value="-Auri=/struts-my-tags" />
            <compilerarg value="-Adescription='My Struts Tags'" />
            <compilerarg value="-AdisplayName='My Struts Tags'" />
            <compilerarg value="-AoutTemplatesDir=${basedir}/dist/taglib-doc" />
            <compilerarg value="-AoutFile=${basedir}/bin/META-INF/struts-my-tags.tld" />
        </javac>
</target>
```

When I run this the task completes successfully however nothing is generated in the struts-my-tags.tld.

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: This can be a problem: -AtlibVersion=1.0.1, this must be a valid decimal value. Try to change it to -AtlibVersion=1.1

Answer (score 0):

The processor was implemented against the APT interface. 
So the about would never worked.
I ported the APT version to implement the new Java Annotation Processor

[struts-annotation-processor](https://github.com/lunaspeed/struts-annotation-processor)